# Limits to the growth of the volume of a union of spheres

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, combinatorial-geometry

Assume that $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,m$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the maximal distance between any two of them being at most $1$. Define
$$ a(r)=\mu\Bigl(\bigcup_{i=1}^m B(x_i,r)\Bigr),$$
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure and $B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

Clearly $a$ is an increasing, piecewise differentiable function.

Is there an upper bound on the derivative $a'(r)$ for $r_1\le r\le r_2$, depending *only* on $r_1$ and $r_2$ but not on $m$ or the points $x_i$, assuming $0<r_1<r_2<\infty$?

Clearly, if all the balls are disjoint, $a'(r)$ is proportional to $mr^{n-1}$. For any given $r$ we can have $O(r^{-n})$ disjoint balls present, leading to $a'(r)=O(r^{-1})$. Hence the lower bound $r_1$ is necessary. The upper bound is necessary because $a(r)$ would be roughly proportional to $r^n$ when $r$ is very large.

I think a positive answer could lead to a positive answer to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328467/to-show-lebesgue-measure-0/328567), and that is why I ask.

Comment: A very nice question! It feels as though it should be easy to prove, but then it keeps slipping away...

Comment: Shouldn't the upper bound be roughly of the order $r^{n-1}$ is $n$ is large?

Comment: @ElmarZander: Yes, I was really thinking of $a(r)$, not the derivative. Fixed.