# Is the Lebesgue measure of the boundary of a union of $n$-balls zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I'm working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I believe that the question is relevant in any metric space.

Let $B_1^n$ be the closed ball of radius 1 centered at the origin, and let $\oplus$ denote Minkowski addition. For compact $T\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that the set
$$\partial\big( T \oplus B_1^n\big)$$
has 0 Lebesgue measure?

---

Note that $T\oplus B_1^n = \{t+x: t\in T, x\in B_1^n\}$.

Would it help to consider a countably dense subset of $T$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this yourself?

Comment: I would say yes, since sets with boundary whose boundary have positive lebesgue measure tend to be dusty, or very rough. The boundary of a union of balls should be very smooth.

Comment: Related: Vitali covering lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Infinite_version

Answer (score 1):

With a litle more research, I noticed that my set $\partial (T\oplus B_1^n)$ is contained in the set $A$ defined in [this Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328467/to-show-that-the-set-point-distant-by-1-of-a-compact-set-has-lebesgue-measure-0). So, yes, it has Lebesgue measure 0.